# Ansible vsphere_guest error

Tags: ansible, pysphere

I try to auto create some VM i can say the CODE was working as it was ... I was able to create 20 VM on the fly! 
Now I upgrade my Ansible from 
Ansible 1.8.4
  configured module search path = None
TO

Ansible 1.9.0.1
  configured module search path = None

As I upgrade my pysphere from 0.1.7 to 0.1.8 (pysphere-0.1.8-py2.7.egg-info)
the only reason for the upgrade is `relocate()` function in 0.1.8.

So now I try to run my Ansible code and I get this ERROR

```
failed: [host1] => {"failed": true}
msg: unsupported parameter for module: username

tasks:
    - debug: var=vm
    - name: Gather VM facts
      vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: vcenter name
        password: pass
        username: user
        guest: ansible
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
```

```
REMOTE_MODULE vsphere_guest vcenter_hostname=XXXXXXXXX guest=ansible password=VALUE_HIDDEN username=    <------  MISSING !!!! why ??
```

I install new server and go back to old version: same issue so … 
how can I get more detail log?

What am I missing?

Thanks 
Noam

Comment: Can you post full output with `-vvvv`?

Comment: REMOTE_MODULE vsphere_guest vcenter_hostname=XXXXXX guest=ansible password=VALUE_HIDDEN username=
EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427644203.58-81939458313131 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427644203.58-81939458313131']
PUT /tmp/tmppctHF7 TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427644203.58-81939458313131/vsphere_guest EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/env python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427644203.58-81939458313131/vsphere_guest; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1427644203.58-81939458313131/ >/dev/null 2>&1']

Comment: i think maby this is vcenter issue but i dont see any way or error on the server i can tell you that i run the command and did netstat to see it connection to the vcenter is come up but no ... so i try using python 2.7 and try to connect to vcenter and it worked ... i am lost :-(

Answer (score 0):

OK i fix it ! yes i am idiot ! 50% :)

by default ansible is try to find folder named library in this folder you put some 
new  module and i download vsphere_guest.py from some site and ansible just use it ! 
the only issue is that i dont understand why in the run you can see that module is from the url or any url :)

case closed many thanks